# Using QTP in Multi-tier Environment

Tags: testing, qtp

We have a system A and a system B, connected by system O. 
System O help to convert data between System A and System B.

Till now I used to manually Test this evnironment like this:

```
Step 1. Trigger data from System A, check system A ports such that data were sent out of System A.
Step 2. Confirm that data was received & transported by System O.
Step 3. Confirm that data reached System B, and was processed.
```

I need to somehow Automate the entire testing scenario. 
I have only limited skill of using QTP. 
I can at most automate only one System at a time.

May I know to how to Automate the entire test scenario i.e. the single automation must process through all the 3 above steps.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "*can at most automate only one System at a time..."*, I don't understand what stops you from automating the whole thing.

If by any technical reason QTP does not support that you interact with such systems in the same script, you could still automate all 3 steps independently, chain them together in another script and make each them "aware" of the results of the previous execution via an output file (for example).

In other words:

QTP Script 1:

- *Trigger data from System A, check system A ports such that data were sent out of System A.*
- Store results in `output1.txt`

QTP Script 2:

- Build internal state based on `output1.txt`
- *Confirm that data was received & transported by System O.*
- Store results in `output2.txt`

QTP Script 3:

- Build internal state based on `output3.txt`
- *Confirm that data reached System B, and was processed*

Use another script (like batch file) to run all 3 scripts together.